# BPM 8.0 support TLS1.2?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, tls1.2, business-process-management

I have BPM 8.0 installed on AIX 7.1, The detailed product version list below:

Question is if this environment support TLS1.2? I am setting up a connection from BPM to IBM MQ, IBM MQ logs showing the remote channel did not specify a CipherSpec when the local channel expected one to be specified.

```
Product List
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BPMPS                    installed
ND                       installed

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM Business Process Manager Advanced V8.0 - Process Server
Version               8.0.1.3
ID                    BPMPS
Build Level           20140814-155433
Build Date            8/14/14
Package               com.ibm.bpm.PS.V80_8.0.1003.20140814_1722
Architecture          PPC64
Installed Features    Production
                      Business Process Manager Advanced - Client (always installed)

Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server Network Deployment
Version               8.0.0.13
ID                    ND
Build Level           cf131705.01
Build Date            2/1/17
Package               com.ibm.websphere.ND.v80_8.0.13.20170202_0013
Architecture          PPC64
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit SDK for Java, Version 6
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Java Version:
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6460_26sr8fp35ifix-20170120_01(SR8 FP35+IV90630+IV90578+IX90178))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.6.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20161005_321286 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8_20161005_1305_B321286
JIT  - tr.r11_20161001_125404
GC   - R26_Java626_SR8_20161005_1305_B321286_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20161005_321286)
JCL  - 20161020_01
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

MQ Logs:

```
----- amqzfubx.c : 624 -------------------------------------------------------- 08/01/17 17:54:55 - Process(6619304.1735) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(test.test.com) Installation(Installation2)
                    VRMF(7.5.0.6) QMgr(MQ******)

AMQ9639: Remote channel '***.SVRCONN' did not specify a CipherSpec.

EXPLANATION: Remote channel '***.SVRCONN' did not specify a CipherSpec when the local channel expected one to be specified.

The remote host is ''test.test.com (1**.1**.1**.1**)' .

The channel did not start. ACTION: Change the remote channel '***.SVRCONN' on host 'test.test.com (1**.1**.1**.1**)' to specify a CipherSpec so that both ends of the channel have matching CipherSpecs.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is really the wrong place to ask about software compatibility or installation/configuration for any of WebSphere, MQ or IBM BPM.  Try [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/), [IBM Developerworks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/forum?id=11111111-0000-0000-0000-000000000266) or, best of all, open a PMR with IBM technical support.

Comment: What ciphersuit are you specifying on the client side and what cipherspec on the SVRCONN channel.

Comment: Combo ----- Cipher Spec ----- Cipher Suite ------  Protocol ---

1 -- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256  --  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 -- TLS 1.2
2 -- TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256  --  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 -- TLS 1.2

MQ have Cipher Spec defined, BPM have Cipher Suite defined. No.1 and 2 tested , both failed .

Comment: Thank you for your comments .

Comment: Hope my answer was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you provided you have attempted to use both of the following SHA2 CipherSuites:

```
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

---

**Short answer:**

No you would be unable to use a SHA2 CipherSuite with the current versions of products you are using.

---

**Details:**

You are running IBM BPM [8.0.1.3](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27036594#fp8013) which was released August 15 2014 and will be [End of Support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg3t949273n55566i48) September 30 2017.

In the link above it is noted that BPM 8.0.1.3 is bundled with WAS 8.0.0.9 however the output shows you are running [8.0.0.13](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27022958#80013) which was released February 20 2017 and will be [End of Support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg3u361173s77642c22) April 30 2018.

WAS 8.0.0.13 is [shipped with](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21248089) IBM MQ RA [7.0.1.3](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27014224#70113) which was released August 13 2015.  The main MQ product went [End of Support](https://www-01.ibm.com/software/support/lifecycleapp/PLCDetail.wss?q45=B970095C63279Y22) September 30 2015, but this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21674407#EOS8) states the RA would still be supported because it is bundled with a supported version of BPM.

According to the IBM MQ v7.0.1 Knowledge Center page "[SSL CipherSpecs and CipherSuites](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm34740_.htm)", this version of MQ does **not** support either of those SHA2 CipherSuites or any TLS 1.2 CipherSuite.

The Queue Manager error log entry notes it is at 7.5.0.6 which according to the IBM MQ v7.5 Knowledge Center page "[SSL CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032470_.htm)" does show support for one of the two SHA2 CipherSuites you tried.  I know based on some KC feedback I provided and APAR [IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) that it actually supports both but the page has not yet been updated.  Please see the equivalent IBM MQ Classes for Java page "[SSL CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in WebSphere MQ classes for Java](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031290_.htm)" which has been updated to list both.

---

**Conclusion:**

In order to have IBM MQ SHA2 support you need to use a IBM MQ RA v7.1 or higher, this version of IBM MQ is currently out of support as a product but is bundled with WAS 8.5 which is bundled with BPM v8.5, since BPM 8.0 is end of support at the end of next month this is hopefully something you are already planning for.

Comment: Thank you JoshMc. Could you please also check this link ?
https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/351300/is-there-support-for-tls-12-for-bpm-using-java-6-o/

Comment: It say IBM Java SR10 support TLS1.2, But I found SR8 in my java version output, I am not quite sure what my exact java version is , if I can upgrade IBM java to SR10 to try ? Thanks

Comment: MQ v7.0.1.x does not support TLS1.2 CipherSuites no matter what version of Java you are using.

Comment: Please see my answer details and conclusion.  BPM 8.0.1.3 uses MQ 7.0.1.13.  You need to move to BPM 8.5 which uses MQ 7.1.